# Add percent character after every second character with Regex

Tags: java, regex, hex, ascii

I want to create a regex that will add the percent character '%' in front of every second character in a Hex string. I also would like a leading percentage character.

For example, the Hex '54657374696E67' in ASCII is 'testing'. In my query I need it to end up being '%54%65%73%74%69%6E%67'.

Can a regex do this? I am using Java's regex library.

Comment: Why a regex? You can do this more simply within than with one.

Comment: This limitation is due to the platform being used to work with the values.

Comment: The only platform you've mentioned is the Java regex library, and there is nothing that obliges you to use that. Regular expressions don't replace things, they match things.

Comment: @EJP That is why I was asking if it was possible. Sin properly answered the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find `(?i)([a-f0-9]{2})`
Replace `%$1`

Comment: Is there a way to this without using a Java method?

Comment: I don't know of any api string function utility that does this. Use a regex replace method. There is that a-f thing to contend with.